# Produce a list of colours against all other colours

Tags: mysql, sql

As the title may suggest, I'm in need for some guidance. Currently what I have is rather close, it's just that one of each colour is repeating itself and I cant seems to get my head around it.

Here is my table:

```
  CREATE TABLE Colors
   (c_ID VARCHAR2(3) NOT NULL,
    c_NAME VARCHAR2(11));

  INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
    ('T01','RED');
  INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
    ('T02','BLUE');
  INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
    ('T03','BLACK');
  INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
    ('T04','YELLOW');
  INSERT INTO Colors VALUES
    ('T05','ORANGE');
```

The query that I used:

```
 select distinct a.c_name as "HOME", s.c_name as "AWAY"
 from colors a, colors s
 order by a.c_name;
```

The results come as:

```
 Black     Black
 Black     Blue
 Black     Orange
 Black     Red
 Black     Yellow
```

This happens for each colour, but as you can see there is always a scenario where each colour repeats against itself. How can I get rid of that without deleting? Thanks in advance.

Comment: add this `where a.t_name <> s.t_name`

Comment: Well, your question was efficiently answered. Just to contribute with something, you can perform one insert statement near `INSERT INTO Colors (c_ID, c_NAME) VALUES ('T01','RED'), ('T02','BLUE'), ('T03','BLACK'), ('T04','YELLOW'), ('T05','ORANGE');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just change your query like this:

```
select distinct a.t_name as "HOME", s.t_name as "AWAY"
from teams a, teams s
where a.t_name <> s.t_name -- or this if you need to check on id instead a.t_id <> s.t_id
order by a.t_name;
```